# What component should I use? H-bridge? Relay?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, resistors

I am working on a senior design project that involves regulating the noise from headphones to make sure no damage to the ear is done. I have all parts working except the part necessary to switch the unregulated audio input to a regulated one which would turn the sound level down. I have tested Solid state relays, and am currently trying to use a digital potentiometer to automatically increase the resistance of the audio like to decrease the sound. Could I use an H bridge also to switch between two possible outputs (no resistance vs resistance) and if so should I?

Comment: What you should do is create  an AGC design or a soft limiter using feedback.

Comment: H-bridges are used to allow a circuit to drive current through a load in both directions so it is inapplicable here.

Comment: How do you intend to quantify the limit point since that depends on the transducers within the headphones?

Comment: @PaulUszak I’ve created an equation that relates the applied voltage to the earbuds and the respective decibel output, and then just built a multimeter with arduino that uses that equation. I sample a voltage every 10 ms and integrate with that time interval. Once the Db*s exposure reaches a value specified unsafe by OSHA, I intend to decrease the volume in some way. Actually works much better than I thought.

Comment: Okay. What do you want to happen when the limit is reached?  If the sound gets to 200dB and a simple resistor/H bridge limiter kicks in, the sound will suddenly jump low.  And power spikes above the limit will cause annoying level 'wobble'.  Are looking for something as sophisticated as gradual limiting to an asymptotic level?  That's more like EE75's auto gain control and way more than a single resistor.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem then?

Comment: @PaulUszak i was just looking for something simple, audio quality is not as important for me just as to get it working. I’ve ran some of the audio through a resistor to test and a 330 ohm resistor decreases the audio to a safe limit. I did notice some of the wobble but I think it would be fine for my purposes.

Comment: Just use a relay if it's a school project. Might have to be a dry switching relay, and never run it wet or else it may not be able to conduct dry signals anymore. Dry is a low-current signal, wet is high current. Arcing when interrupt higher currents produces corrosion which inhibits low voltage, low current signals from being able to punch through.

Comment: @JakeBlocker - I'm having a hard time to visualize how an H-bridge could be used for your purpose. You may want to include a drawing showing what you're proposing to make it more clear for us, so we can better advise you. Using a digital potentiometer right at the headphone pin signal is probably not a good idea due to the current handling capability - usually the max current on those is just a couple of milliamps.

Comment: Does this give you some ideas?: http://www.thatcorp.com/Design_Notes.shtml

Comment: A H-Bridge or a solenoid relay seems too bulky a hardware for headphones. I would rather look for some chanel selector IC's, analog signal drivers....

Answer (score 1):

You could use three DPDT relays to get 4 sound levels on two channels:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHXGqE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't expect you'd be able to get it to respond fast enough to protect hearing in something like a shooting range though. It might be okay for something like an aircraft mechanic.